# write each row of a csv file as a list in a different dictionary key python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I need to have the each row of a csv file as a list which would in turn be the value to a particular dictionary key.
The next row would be the list which acts as value for some other key of the same dictionary.
Here's the code :

```
 tehsils_in_district=defaultdict
   i = 1
   with open("district_list.csv",'rb') as f:
     for row in csv.reader(f):
        tehsils_in_district[i] = row
        i = i+1
```

Comment: SO what's the problem?

Comment: `defaultdict` needs to be called to actually create such a dictionary object. The argument must be a callable which creates a new value for a key which doesn't exist yet. But given the loop body a regular dictionary would suffice because there is never a non-existing key accessed. And instead of manually initialising and incrementing `i` one would use the `enumerate()` function. Also a dictionary with ascending integer values as keys is a code smell as a list seems to be a simpler structure for this.